# Strange behaviour with C# SQL

Tags: c#, sql

```
string sql = "SELECT column1 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.table2ID = table2.table2ID where column1 = \"testData\"";
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader["column1"].ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The above SQL query works fine when there is without the where clause and I able to writeline "testData". But when I restrict the condition, then its giving me sqlException saying that "testData" is an invalid column?

Comment: Try to use single quotes arround column1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use single quotes to specify a string in SQL.

So

```
string sql = "SELECT column1 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.table2ID = table2.table2ID where column1 = 'testData'";
```

Comment: You need to remove the backslashes

Comment: The Sybase docs are full of double quotes in examples, and surprise, it does not work...

Answer (score 2):

You should use parameters to avoid such problems.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `\'` just use `'`.

```
string sql = "SELECT column1 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.table2ID = table2.table2ID where column1 = 'testData'";
```